# Regex to search section number which not starts with "0" in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

regex 1: `^(\d{1,3}\.(:\d+\.?)*)[\s]?([(|\[]?([a-zA-Z]{1}|\d{0,3}|(?=[xvi])M*D?C{0,4}L?x{0,4}v?i{0,4})[\]|)|:|.])?(?!\S)`

This regex searches `"1."`, `"23."`, `"1.(a)"`, `"10."`

But it should not search `"0."`

regex 2: `^[\s]*([1-9]{1,3}[)])(?!\S)`

This regex searches `"1)"`, `"23)"`

But it should not search `"0)"`

Comment: Could you, please, specify all valid section numbers? E.g. is `I.X (15a).479-2.32 ` valid?

Comment: You should ask about the problem you're trying to solve rather than asking about how to fix your solution

Comment: regex1:- "1.", "0.(a)", "1.(IV)", "0.(viii)"

Comment: while searching for section number, i am getting "0)" as section number due to my regex. As "0)" could not be a section number. Please help me to get a regex which don't find "0)".

Comment: Replace every instance of `\d` that matches the FIRST digit in every possible pattern with `[1-9]`

Comment: @TianvanHeerden i tried this but it don't read "10."

Answer (score 0):

decimal number not starting with 0

[1-9]+.[0-9]